# asyncio выдает ошибку

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

я пытаюсь запустить асинхронную функцию aiogram через asyncio и она как бы работает но тревожит ошибка которую она выдает

```
from aiogram import Bot
import asyncio
bot = Bot(token='token')

async def send():
    await bot.send_message(645903918, 'hello')
    print("KRUT")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [loop.create_task(send()), loop.create_task(send())]

wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
loop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
loop.close()
```

код ошибки:

```
    Unclosed client session
    client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001E6BE496BB0>
    Unclosed connector
    connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x000001E6BECD6880>, 1065118.593), (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x000001E6BECBFA60>, 1065118.64)]']
    connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x000001E6BE496AC0>
    Fatal error on SSL transport
    protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x000001E6BECB9940>
    transport: <_ProactorSocketTransport fd=376 read=<_OverlappedFuture cancelled>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 684, in _process_write_backlog
        self._transport.write(chunk)
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 359, in write
        self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 395, in _loop_writing
        self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
    Exception ignored in: <function _SSLProtocolTransport.__del__ at 0x000001E6BD3B2A60>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 321, in __del__
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 316, in close
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 593, in _start_shutdown
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 598, in _write_appdata
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 706, in _process_write_backlog
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 720, in _fatal_error
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 151, in _force_close
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
    Fatal error on SSL transport
    protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x000001E6BE496A90>
    transport: <_ProactorSocketTransport fd=512 read=<_OverlappedFuture cancelled>>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 684, in _process_write_backlog
        self._transport.write(chunk)
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 359, in write
        self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 395, in _loop_writing
        self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
    Exception ignored in: <function _SSLProtocolTransport.__del__ at 0x000001E6BD3B2A60>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 321, in __del__
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 316, in close
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 593, in _start_shutdown
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 598, in _write_appdata
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 706, in _process_write_backlog
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 720, in _fatal_error
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 151, in _force_close
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Но код ошибки вы нам не дадите, я так понимаю?

Comment: Что вы вообще хотите сделать?

Comment: ой забыл про код ошибки,

Comment: я учусь программировать, я хочу просто чтоб asyncio запускал функцию бота из aiogram, она работает но вот это предупреждение меня тревожит

Comment: Это не ответ. Что конкретно вы хотите сделать?

Comment: ну вот пытаюсь сделать так чтобы asyncio запустил функцию бота

Comment: Ну вообще у aiohttp есть такая заморочка кидать [такое сообщение под windows](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/4324), Толком непонятно как быть. У меня в заметках написано не использовать asyncio.run(), а полный код как у вас делать. Также написано делать `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())` под вин, но это может мешать другим вещам

Answer (score 0):

Думаю проблема в том когда вы делаете цикл из асункио, а делаете вы, я так понимаю до запуска екзекутера. Я сделал вот так (см. ниже) и ошибка пропала.

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("as")


async def send():
    await bot.send_message(200585819, 'hello')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(send())
    loop.close()
```