# Запуск нескольких вечных циклов параллельно

Tags: python, asyncio

У меня есть следующий код

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from settings import *

app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

groups_id = {-1001694: 20, -1001786: 10}  # вместо настоящих айди фейковые


def send(app, id, time):
    while True:
        app.send_message(id, "test222")
        sleep(time)

with app:
    for id, time in groups_id.items():
        send(app, id, time)  # строка запуска
```

так вот вопрос: как запустить send несколько раз, т.е. после "строки запуска" цикл продолжал работать как будто вечного цикла нет, но при этом что бы он на деле работал? я пробовал через асинхронность и паралельность, но ничего не сработало

вот версия асинхронности:

```
from settings import *
import asyncio

app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

groups_id = {-1001694: 20, -1001786: 10}  # вместо настоящих айди фейковые


async def send(app, id, time):
    while True:
        await app.send_message(id, "test222")
        await asyncio.sleep(time)

async def main():
    async with app:
        for id, time in groups_id.items():
            await send(app, id, time)  # строка запуска

asyncio.run(main())
```

но тут итог тот же, отправка только в одну группу

update: спасибо этому человеку за ответ: [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor)

вот итоговый код:

```
from settings import *
import asyncio

app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

groups_id = {-100169: 20, -1001729: 10}  # вместо настоящих айди фейковые


async def send(app, id, time):
    while True:
        await app.send_message(id, "test222")
        await asyncio.sleep(time)

async def main():
    async with app:
        await asyncio.gather(*[send(app, id, time) for id, time in groups_id.items()])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: У вас в коде нет ваших попыток асинхронности или параллельности, поэтому неизвестно, что у вас получилось.

Comment: их нет потому что я удалил, мне просто нужны хоть какие то идеи, получилось у меня во всех случаях то что все равно код "застревает" на цикле

Comment: Вот вам идея в "соседнем" вопросе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1421034/1365 . В send код вставляете свой, только `time.sleep` заменяете на `asyncio.sleep`

Comment: не, ни в каком виде не помогает (в асинхронной версии тоже пробовал)

Comment: Так добавьте что именно вы пробовали, чтобы не гадать, что у вас не получается

Comment: вот, в правке вопроса

Comment: Объявляйте через `async def send`, потом вызов `await send(`

Comment: вот изменил код, но отличий от первого варианта (в плане работы) 0

Comment: Теперь вместо цикла делаете `await asyncio.gather(*[send(app, id, time) for id, time in groups_id.items()])`

Comment: спасибо, сработало, напишешь это как ответ? что бы если что все могли посмотреть у кого такая проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой код:

```
for id, time in groups_id.items():
    await send(app, id, time)  # строка запуска
```

ждёт (await) пока закончится каждый `send`, который у вас бесконечный. Чтобы все отправки работали одновременно, нужно использовать функцию [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather):

```
await asyncio.gather(*[send(app, id, time) for id, time in groups_id.items()])
```

Тут все корутины сначала собираются в список, потом "все вместе" запускаются.

Итоговый код:

```
from settings import *
import asyncio

app = Client("my_account", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)

groups_id = {-100169: 20, -1001729: 10}  # вместо настоящих айди фейковые


async def send(app, id, time):
    while True:
        await app.send_message(id, "test222")
        await asyncio.sleep(time)


async def main():
    async with app:
        await asyncio.gather(*[send(app, id, time) for id, time in groups_id.items()])


asyncio.run(main())
```